# GCC/LD Linking mangled symbols not recognized by JNA

Tags: java, c, gcc, linker, jna

Odd question here not quite sure how to ask it.

I am writing some JNA bindings for a proprietary shared library.

the library api has several functions named things like km_open, km_close, etc.
In c, these functions are defined in the header file as such:

```
Komodo km_open (
    int port_number
);
int km_close (
    Komodo komodo
);
```

and in Java i made JNA bindings for them defined like this:

```
public abstract Komodo km_open(int port_number);
public abstract int km_close(Komodo komodo);
```

but JNA fails to find these symbols in the library.
When I dump the symbols in the binary
i find the following:

```
0000000000008e20 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  Base        net_km_open
0000000000007410 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  Base        c_km_open
0000000000008e40 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  Base        net_km_close
0000000000007430 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  Base        c_km_close
```

I am guessing that because this library is meant to be used by both .net and standalone c applications that these names are mangled to provide alternative versions of the function. and yet I cannot find anything in the demo applications source code that maps the name c_km_open to km_open. yet it compiles in GCC and the code works. How do these symbols get resolved when linking/loading the binary and does JNA have a method of doing the same thing? Currently I can get the JNA bindings to work if I modify the bindings like this:

```
public abstract Komodo c_km_open(int port_number);
public abstract int c_km_close(Komodo komodo);
```

which is an acceptable workaround I just want to understand what is going on in the background here.

Comment: C compilers generally do not perform name mangling, and GCC in particular does not do so.  At least, not by default on typical targets.  There may be some dynamic linking magic going on here that is not evident from the data you have presented; it is plausible that JNA would be oblivious to such gimmicks.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much that I thought, I am just trying to understand where that "magic" is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer, it was kind of tricky, but instead of linking against the .so library file itself, the makefile generated a piece of object code by the same name as the .so library which defined wrapper methods that dynamically loaded the "c_" functions. they then linked to that piece of object code instead of the library. it didn't come up in a search because it was a generated file.
The solution in JNA is then to simply mimic that behavior by creating a wrapper class with the simplified names that make a callback to the JNA bindings